# Javscript - Display alto text without absolute position to handle selection on text

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a backend with OCR function who convert a pdf file intotexts, this returns an array of text :

```
const text = [{top: '10%',left: '8%', value: 'Start of a paragraph'}, {top: '10%',left: '15%', value: 'end of paragraph'}, {top: '12%',left: '8%', value: 'A second line'} ...]
```

I use absolute position to map over texts and display it with React to show it as document

Problem :
Users need select text and they have a lot of troubleshooting with selection cursor, it's very hard to select only one word (all paragraph is selected or the previous word)

Exemple: Try here https://codepen.io/lionel95200x/pen/zYKzwwg to select only "1 second part" text

Do you have a solution to display this texts without absolute position ?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Adding padding-right property to the text you want to select helps in making the text easier to select.

Comment: In codepen exemple, adding padding right not help to select "1 second part"

Comment: Also add &nbsp; in HTML of the element which basically is whitespace that can be selected.